# TSQL автоинкремент при вставке в определенном разрезе данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачку.
В таблице #tBookPrice есть данные, с определённым calcId.
Нужно добавлять в таблицу данные увеличивая искусcтвенный cacId в разрезе code.

сейчас так:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tBookPrice;
CREATE TABLE #tBookPrice(
     id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,name VARCHAR(256)
    ,code VARCHAR(256)
    ,price INTEGER
    ,calcId INTEGER
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tBookPriceTmp;
CREATE TABLE #tBookPriceTmp(
     id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,name VARCHAR(256)
    ,price INTEGER
    ,code VARCHAR(256)
);

INSERT INTO #tBookPrice(
     name
    ,code
    ,price
    ,calcId
)
VALUES
     ('Name 1','B56878',10,1)
    ,('Name 2','H56817',10,1)
    ,('Name 3','Y55617',10,1);

INSERT INTO #tBookPriceTmp(
     name
    ,code
    ,price
)
VALUES
     ('Name 1','B56878',20)
    ,('Name 1','B56878',30)
    ,('Name 1','B56878',40);



INSERT INTO #tBookPrice(
     name
    ,code
    ,price
    ,calcId
)
SELECT
     tData.name
    ,tData.code
    ,tData.price 
    ,(maxCode.maxId + 1) AS calcId
FROM #tBookPriceTmp AS tData
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        code
        ,MAX(calcId) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY code ASC) AS maxId
    FROM #tBookPrice
) AS maxCode
    ON tData.code = maxCode.code


SELECT *
FROM #tBookPrice
ORDER BY code,calcId ASC
```

Получаю не то что нужно:

```
id  name    code    price   calcId
1   Name 1  B56878  10      1
4   Name 1  B56878  20      2
5   Name 1  B56878  30      2
6   Name 1  B56878  40      2
2   Name 2  H56817  10      1
3   Name 3  Y55617  10      1
```

Нужно так:

```
id  name    code    price   calcId
1   Name 1  B56878  10      1
4   Name 1  B56878  20      2
5   Name 1  B56878  30      3
6   Name 1  B56878  40      4
2   Name 2  H56817  10      1
3   Name 3  Y55617  10      1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tBookPrice
SET tBookPrice.calcId = numbered.calcId
FROM ( SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) calcId
       FROM tBookPrice ) numbered
WHERE tBookPrice.id = numbered.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/tUqpfF4E